# OSM place name translations

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

I use osm in my application to determine the name of the rental from a given longitude and latittude, however I sometimes do not have an answer from the OSM server (network is unreachable). I want to know the number of requests allowed, and the restrictions of the OSM.

Comment: Which API exactly? Editing API? Overpass? Nominatim? Something else?

Comment: i use nominatim API.

Comment: The policy is described here: https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/

Comment: @sanastasiadis This is almost an answer :) Just quote the requirements of the policy and provide the link to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the full list of policy rules [here](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/).

Among others here is a list of rules:

The requirements:

> - No heavy uses (an absolute maximum of 1 request per second).
> - Provide a valid HTTP Referer or User-Agent identifying the    application (stock User-Agents as set by http libraries will not do).
> - Clearly display attribution as suitable for your medium.
> - Data is provided under the ODbL license which requires to share alike    (although small extractions are likely to be covered by fair 
>     usage    / fair dealing).

And there is also a set of "Unacceptable usage" rules:

> - Auto-complete search This is not yet supported by Nominatim and you
>     must not implement such a service on the client side using the API.
> - Systematic queries This includes reverse queries in a grid, searching    for complete lists of postcodes, towns etc. and
>     downloading all POIs    in an area. If you need complete sets of data,
>     get it from the OSM    planet or an extract.
> - Scraping of details The details page is there for debugging only and    may not be downloaded automatically.